# line elements inside multiple div's equal

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to line each subject inside a block to the same height.
By subjects I mean the title, content and the button. The biggest problem is the button. When I give the class `.content` a height everything looks nice until I'm changing the zoom of my window of change resolution.

Thanks in advance for you help.

```css
#information_blocks {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(215, 201, 187, 0.9);
    box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px black;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.block {
    /*border: 1px solid #adadad;*/
    display: inline-block;
    flex: 1 1 0 100%;
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.74902) 0 0 15px 0;
    height: auto;
}

.block:first-child {
    margin-left: 9%;
    float: left;
}

.block:last-child {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

.block .container {
    display: block;
    flex: 1 1 100% 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.block .container:last-child {
    margin-top: 5%;
    height: 20%;
}

.block .container .title {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #1b6d85;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.block .container .content {
    display: block;
}

.block .container .button {
    display: block;
    margin: auto auto auto auto;
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #1b6d85;
    color: white;
    line-height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div id="information_blocks">

    <div class="block">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">
                Social media
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean
                massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="button">Learn more</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">


        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">
                Social media
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean
                massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam
                dsfdscsdcdscs
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="button">Learn more</div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">
                Social media
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean
                massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="button">Learn more</div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to **vertically** align the content of each box in the middle?

Comment: Kind of, the most important thing for me is that the buttons line out next to each other on the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give `flex: 0 0 auto` to `.block .container:last-child` and remove `height: 20%` from the button.

Have a look at the working snippet (*hope this is what you are looking for*):

```css
#information_blocks {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(215, 201, 187, 0.9);
    box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px black;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.block {
    /*border: 1px solid #adadad;*/
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.74902) 0 0 15px 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.block:first-child {
    margin-left: 9%;
}

.block:last-child {
    margin-right: 10%;
}

.block .container {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.block .container:last-child {
    flex: 0 0 auto !important;
    margin-top: 5%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.block .container .title {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #1b6d85;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.block .container .content {}

.block .container .button {
    margin: auto auto auto auto;
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #1b6d85;
    color: white;
    line-height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div id="information_blocks">

    <div class="block">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">
                Social media
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean
                massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="button">Learn more</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">


        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">
                Social media
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean
                massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam
                dsfdscsdcdscs
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="button">Learn more</div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">
                Social media
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean
                massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="button">Learn more</div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I get what you mean, but this is something I don't want at all. I want 3 div's that have the same height as the biggest one and the button lined on the bottom. But thanks for you answer

Comment: @Casper Updated my answer, please have a look. And don't forget to accept it if it works for you.

Comment: Its my pleasure @Casper

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna have to restructure the entire thing, I'm afraid. I would recommend using a table-like structure for that:

HTML

```
<div class="display-table">
    <div class="display-table-row">
        <div class="display-table-cell">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean
        </div>
        <div class="display-table-cell">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam Lorem ips
        </div>
        <div class="display-table-cell">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="display-table-row">
        <div class="display-table-cell">
            <button>
                button
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="display-table-cell">
            <button>
                button
            </button>       </div>
        <div class="display-table-cell">
            <button>
                button
            </button>       
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.display-table {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.display-table-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.display-table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top; // change this to "middle" if you want to vertically align the content
    width: 1%;
}
```

JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/riyemizaqi/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot that a table also was a option

Answer (score 1):

Another way of solving this is to add `padding-bottom: 100px;` and `position: relative;` to the `.block` element, and then `position: absolute;` the `.button`.

Working jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xxpzzxuy/).

CSS amendments:

```
.block {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

Whole code below to keep answer self-contained.

```
<div id="information_blocks">

    <div class="block">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">
                Social media
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean
                massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="button">Learn more</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">


        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">
                Social media
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean
                massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam
                dsfdscsdcdscs
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="container">
            <div class="button">Learn more</div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">
                Social media
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean
                massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam
            </div>
        </div>


           <div class="container">
            <div class="button">Learn more</div>
        </div>

    </div>


</div>

#information_blocks {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(215, 201, 187, 0.9);
    box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px black;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.block {
    /*border: 1px solid #adadad;*/
    display: inline-block;
    flex: 1 1 0 100%;
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.74902) 0 0 15px 0;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.block:first-child {
    margin-left: 9%;
    float: left;
}

.block:last-child {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

.block .container {
    display: block;
    flex: 1 1 100% 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.block .container:last-child {
    margin-top: 5%;
    height: 20%;
}

.block .container .title {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #1b6d85;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.block .container .content {
    display: block;
}

.button {
    display: block;
    margin: auto auto auto auto;
    width: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #1b6d85;
    color: white;
    line-height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    bottom: 20px;
}
```